# emacs で、 tmux でいうところの balance-window はできますか？

Tags: emacs

emacs で縦ウィンドウ分割を行っていくと、例えば 1/2, 1/4, 1/4 で分割されます。これを、 1/3, 1/3, 1/3 になるように、高さを調整したいのですが、これを実現する機能はありますか。

Comment: その名もズバリ、`balance-windows` という関数があって、デフォルトでは `C-x +` に割り当てられています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M-x balance-windows`, `C-x +` で実現できました。